# REGEX to find the class name for style property in html file

Tags: html, regex

Hello friends I got a requirement to find the class for the styple property in html file.For that I have to use REGEX. Please check below details

property is **font-style:italic**

corresponding class that i should find out is **.csF52F8E4D**

please check below link for the requirement.

https://regex101.com/r/rIkAaN/1

the Regular expression that i wrote is

`(\.(..........){.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;font-style:italic;})`

can any one please help me how to identify the class name for the given property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookaheads:

```
\.[\w-]+(?=[^{}]*{[^{}]*font-style\s*:\s*italic)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIkAaN/2)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could generalize it where the selector is in group 1.

`(\.[^{}]+?)\s*{[^{}]*?font-style\s*:\s*italic;[^{}]*?}`

https://regex101.com/r/rIkAaN/5

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      \.
      [^{}]+? 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* 
 {
 [^{}]*? 
 font-style
 \s* : \s* 
 italic
 ;
 [^{}]*? 
 }
```